# SQL Server Granted Permission not Working

Tags: sql-server, permissions

A user had an issue with a login to an application.  The error is "The Update permission was denied on the object '{tablename}', database '{databasename}, schema 'dbo'.

The user already has permissions based on a role that already allowed other users to properly login, making the necessary entry into the "log" table.

When checking the user with this code,

```
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = N'[AD UserName]';
SELECT 
    permission_name AS [Permission]
FROM fn_my_permissions(N'[ServerName]', N'DATABASE')
ORDER BY permission_name;
REVERT;
```

**the results were:**

```
CONNECT
EXECUTE
SELECT
VIEW ANY COLUMN ENCRYPTION KEY DEFINITION
VIEW ANY COLUMN MASTER KEY DEFINITION
```

**I expected this:**

```
CONNECT
DELETE
EXECUTE
INSERT
SELECT
UPDATE
VIEW ANY COLUMN ENCRYPTION KEY DEFINITION
VIEW ANY COLUMN MASTER KEY DEFINITION
```

I granted Insert, Update, Delete and Execute directly to the user for the database. The permissions were still not showing Insert, Execute or Delete and still the user can not log in.

I applied permissions directly to the table.  Again the user could not access the application due to the error when inserting into the table.

Additionally the user has access to other DB's on the server but I am not able to find why on this database the user's granted permissions are not correctly applied.

Where can I find if permissions are being altered due to server level permissions or other ideas i am not able to think of.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Perhaps a permission is denied either directly or via role membership. DENY takes precedence over GRANT.

Comment: Is it possible that the login is mapped to a differently named database user? It's customary to `create user [domain\FooUser] from login [domain\FooUser]` but there's nothing preventing `create user [domain\FooUser] from login [domain\BarUser]`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the user was part of a group that had db_denywriter checked on the same database.

The question still remains what is the best way to determine the permissions of a user, even if it's through a group permission, are denied or granted.

The lack of something should not equate to true, or false.

Thanks!

Comment: `Deny` overrides any `grant` so this is correct. You need to also check for a deny